# Prove that for any complex number $|x|=|-x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> Prove that for any complex number $|x|=|-x|$

So we can substitute $a+bi$ for $x$, so the equation becomes $$|a+bi|=|-a-bi|$$

I don't know how to continue; sorry if it is really obvious and I missed it...

Comment: Do you know the formula for $|x|$ if $x=a+bi$?

Comment: I feel like I should know...but I forgot...is it $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, yes. Plug $-x$ into that formula.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Why do I always miss this kind of obvious stuff?

Comment: Now repeat for $$|x| = \left|\left(\cos t + i \sin t\right)x\right|,$$ with $t$ a any real number.

Comment: @SeanLake what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that's a more general equation you can prove with nothing more than algebra and the following identity: $$\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1.$$

Comment: @SeanLake Oh ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ |x|= |a+ib| = \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{ (-a)^2 + (-b)^2 } = |-a-bi|= |-x| $$

Answer (score 2):

Just $|x|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $|-x|=\sqrt{(-a)^2+(-b)^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Hence $|x|=|-x|$

Comment: I think you want to write $|-x|=\sqrt{(-a)^2+(-b)^2}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;\;|x|^2=x \cdot \overline{x}=(-x)(-\overline{x}) = (-x)\overline{(-x)} = |-x|^2$

Comment: What does $\overline{x}$ mean? I only know it as "not $x$"...

Comment: @suomynonA That's a common notation for the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks